# R package with both .c and .cpp files with Rcpp

Tags: c, rcpp, r-package

I'm trying to build an R package which contains both C (in the form of .c files) and C++ code (in the form of .cpp files) using the Rcpp package as a dependency.

I have a couple of questions.

1. First, is it actually possible to do this? Can one call C scripts and C++ scripts that are in the same R package?
2. If the previous is possible, how then does one properly register the functions in the C and C++ scripts.

To help with this, I have set up a little example which is available on my GitHub page (https://github.com/tpbilton/testrcpp). I have used `Rcpp.package.skeleton("testrcpp")` to initialize the package and added some functions (from this tutorial https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/Rcpp/vignettes/Rcpp-introduction.pdf) and then ran `Rcpp::compileAttributes()`. I installed the package and the c++ function `convolve_cpp` works fine but the `convolve_c` is not registered and I have no idea how to do this properly and my attempts at trying to register both functions have gone nowhere.

Answer (score 9):

> First, is it actually possible to do this? Can one call C scripts and C++ scripts that are in the same R package?

Yes. *Rcpp* very famously is taking advantage of *R*'s *C* API. (c.f. [Section 1.6.4 Portable C and C++ code](https://cran.r-project.org/doc/manuals/r-release/R-exts.html#Portable-C-and-C_002b_002b-code) of [Writing R Extensions](https://cran.r-project.org/doc/manuals/r-release/R-exts.html)
.

> If the previous is possible, how then does one properly register the functions in the C and C++ scripts.

Ideally, only surface aspects from the *C++* script. Otherwise, you're stuck writing the glue.

I've taken this approach. The post goes on to detail the slight changes. A working example can be found off-site at:

https://github.com/r-pkg-examples/rcpp-and-c

---

In short, we'll create a header file for the function definitions and include it with the *C* code. From there, we'll create a third file that is in *C++* and export that function into *R* using _Rcpp.

#### convolve_in_c.h

Here we use an inclusion guard via `#ifndef` and `#define` to ensure the function definitions are not repeated if we reuse the header file multiple times.

```
#ifndef CONVOLVE_C_H
#define CONVOLVE_C_H

SEXP convolve_c(SEXP a, SEXP b);

#endif /* CONVOLVE_C_H */
```

#### convolve_in_c.c

Now, let's modify the file to allow for our custom header.

```
#include <R.h>
#include <Rinternals.h>

// Incorporate our header
#include "convolve_in_c.h"

SEXP convolve_c(SEXP a, SEXP b) {
  int na, nb, nab;
  double *xa, *xb, *xab;
  SEXP ab;
  a = PROTECT(coerceVector(a, REALSXP));
  b = PROTECT(coerceVector(b, REALSXP));
  na = length(a); nb = length(b);
  nab = na + nb - 1;
  ab = PROTECT(allocVector(REALSXP, nab));
  xa = REAL(a); xb = REAL(b); xab = REAL(ab);
  for(int i = 0; i < nab; i++)
    xab[i] = 0.0;
  for(int i = 0; i < na; i++)
    for(int j = 0; j < nb; j++)
      xab[i + j] += xa[i] * xb[j];
  UNPROTECT(3);
  return ab;
}
```

#### convolve_from_c_to_rcpp.cpp

Finally, we incorporate the *C* code using `extern` within our *C++* file to have the function name in *C++* align with the *C* linkage. In addition, we manipulate the data type from `SEXP` to `NumericVector`.

```
#include "Rcpp.h"

// Define the method signature

#ifdef __cplusplus
extern "C" {
#endif

#include "convolve_in_c.h"

#ifdef __cplusplus
}
#endif

//' Call C function from Rcpp
//' 
//' Uses the convolve_c function inside of a C++ routine by Rcpp.
//' 
//' @param a,b A `numeric` vector.
//' 
//' @return 
//' A `numeric` vector of length \eqn{N_a + N_b}.
//' 
//' @examples
//' 
//' convolve_from_c(1:5, 5:1)
//' 
//' @export
// [[Rcpp::export]]
Rcpp::NumericVector convolve_from_c(const Rcpp::NumericVector& a,
                                    const Rcpp::NumericVector& b) {

  // Compute the result in _C_ from _C++_.
  SEXP ab = convolve_c(a, b);

  // Cast as an _Rcpp_ NumericVector 
  Rcpp::NumericVector result( ab );

  // Alternatively:
  // Rcpp::NumericVector result( convolve_c(a, b) );

  // Return result
  return result;
}
```

Comment: That's approximately the same as my answer, but longer.  Actually, it's not as you are forcing yourself to rewrite his C function.

Comment: Who needs brevity? ;) In all seriousness, it's a larger implementation of the third option through a working package.

Comment: Not really a re-write of the _C_ function. I'm just placing the _C_ function definition in a header file and calling it from _C++_ whereas you are doing the `extern` include within the _C++_ file.

Comment: Smaller delta. Fewer changes. Smaller difference to OP's approach.

Answer (score 7):

It helps to step back and review.  Consider two packages:

- `convolve_c` which you write by hand as a C only package in 'long-form' and do everything manually, including handcrafting the initialization and registration
- `convolve_cpp` which you write using Rcpp -- and `compileAttributes()` and other tools do everything for you.

In essence, you question amount to *also having the C part done for you by Rcpp* and it just doesn't work that way. Rcpp does not 'see' your `src/convolvec.c` so it won't add it.

But if you look at how these function registrations work -- thousand of CRAN packages to look at, and a manual to peruse -- then you *can* fill it by hand.

Or you could punt. Just add a third function, in C++, which calls your C function.  Rcpp will take care of everything, and you're done.  Your choice: easy, or elaborate.

*Edit:* To be more explicit, option 3 consists of adding

```
#include <Rcpp.h>

extern "C" SEXP convolve_c(SEXP a, SEXP b);

// [[Rcpp::export]]
SEXP callCconvolve(SEXP a, SEXP b) {
    return convolve_c(a, b);
}
```

Then run `compileAttributes()` and all is good. The mixing and matching will work too for the usual reason but is more work -- see "Writing R Extensions" for all the details.

Illustration of it working:

```
R> library(testrcpp)
R> a <- as.double(1:10)
R> b <- as.double(10:1)
R> identical(convolve_cpp(a, b), callCconvolve(a, b))
[1] TRUE
R>
```

Comment: Thanks Dirk. So if I understand you correctly, I have to have two packages, one for the C code and another for the C++ code? I can't just manually register `convolve_c` on top of the having `convolve_cpp` registered by `compileAttributes()`?

Comment: You misunderstand. I laid out two options (with the two packages) trying to explain that by having _one joint_ package *you* still have to do the work of _both halves_.  Or, you punt, and add a trivial C++ caller to your c function. That would get wrapped.   It also sounds you are overcomplicating things for no obvious reason so maybe you want to rethink the why and how.  But in short, you can *always* do everything manually too that is done by helpers for you.  Nothing is stopping you.

Comment: Oh right, I see what you mean now (sorry I have a tendency to over complicate things).

Comment: There is nothing wrong with that as a research device to understand things. Just remember to step back once in a while to get the bigger picture.