# Rcpp package registering both .C and .Call Symbols: compileAttributes() wrongly exports .C symbol as .Call symbol

Tags: r, rcpp

I am writing an R package mainly in Rcpp (thus using `// [[Rcpp::export]]` and `compileAttributes()` to export my functions), but my /src directory also includes a few .c files taken from other packages. Up to this point these were all `.Call` functions which `compileAttributes()` faithfully finds and exports, but now I have the issue with a `.C` function which `compileAttributes()` unfortunately also exports like the others. In particular my `RcppExports.cpp` looks like this:

```
#include <Rcpp.h>
using namespace Rcpp;

... all .cpp functions

RcppExport SEXP pacf1(SEXP, SEXP); 
RcppExport void multi_yw(void *, void *, void *, void *, void *, void *, void *, void *, void *, void *); // This is the .C function wrongly exported here.
// ... and some other .c functions

static const R_CallMethodDef CallEntries[] = {
    ... all .cpp functions
    {"multi_yw", (DL_FUNC) &multi_yw, 10}, // This is the .C function wrongly exported here.
    {"pacf1",    (DL_FUNC) &pacf1,     2},
    ... and some other .c functions
    {NULL, NULL, 0}
};

RcppExport void R_init_mypackage(DllInfo *dll) {
    R_registerRoutines(dll, NULL, CallEntries, NULL, NULL);
    R_useDynamicSymbols(dll, FALSE);
}
```

Instead of the above, I am of course expecting an additional entry like:

```
static const R_CMethodDef CEntries[]  = {
  {"multi_yw", (DL_FUNC) &multi_yw, 10},
  {NULL, NULL, 0}
};
```

And then at the end it should be:

```
RcppExport void R_init_mypackage(DllInfo *dll) {
    R_registerRoutines(dll, CEntries, CallEntries, NULL, NULL);
    R_useDynamicSymbols(dll, FALSE);
}
```

So what can I do here? I figgurred I could probably remove all the `// [[Rcpp::export]]` tags and manually set up a `RcppExports.cpp`, but perhaps there is a solution with `compileAttributes()`? 
Related to this, I also wondered whether I could export the .cpp function symbols with a prefix "CPP_" and the others with "C_" prefix and use `.C / .Call` them directly in my R code (as I am never directly using an exported .cpp function and thus don't really need the R-function wrapper acound `.Call('_mypackage_myfun', ...)` generated by `compileAttributes()`. Thanks for helpful suggestions.

Comment: That is a more complicated situation than what we usually recommend, and have coded for.  I think there are some prior questions here on the site you should consult on this.  I also think that you _primary_ difficulty comes from the initialization / registration which ... you could/should maybe just do by hand.

Comment: Thanks @DirkEddelbuettel . So in my case would removing // [[Rcpp::export]] from all functions and manually editing RcppExports.cpp solve my problem? I have also read about [[Rcpp::init]]. Could that help here for the .C function?

Comment: No, I did not suggest to remove `// [[Rcpp::export]]` and to do without `compileAttributes()`.  You want both.  But your C files may get in the way, so you have work to do.  Please try, if you can, to search prior discussion of this here.

Comment: This is one such question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54000015/r-package-with-both-c-and-cpp-files-with-rcpp/54000236

Answer (score 0):

Ok, so I found a workaround which allows me to .Call and .C external functions and also to .Call directly customized cpp symbols from R code: The recipe is:

2.) create a header file `mysymbols.h`, and include in it for every cpp function the line of code starting with "RcppExport" in RcppExports.cpp, i.e. `RcppExport SEXP _mypackage_mycppfun(SEXP agr1SEXP, SEXP arg2SEXP, SEXP arg3SEXP);` for cpp function mycppfun.

1.) create `my_RcppExports.cpp` in /src, but leave `RcppExports.cpp` intact. In that file put `#include "mysymbols.h"` and `#include <Rcpp.h>`, `using namespace Rcpp;`, at the top paste all the C-functions you want to export like `RcppExport SEXP mycfun(SEXP, SEXP);`. Below paste the `static const R_CallMethodDef CallEntries[] = {...` block from `RcppExports.cpp`, in that block you can add the C-functions to be called with .Call, and you can rename the symbols to anything you want. You can now also create a similar `static const R_CMethodDef CEntries[]  = {...` block listing all the functions to be called with .C. At last, include

```
RcppExport void R_init_mypackage(DllInfo *dll) {
  R_registerRoutines(dll, CEntries, CallEntries, NULL, NULL);
  R_useDynamicSymbols(dll, FALSE);
}
```

When you compileAttributes again, the symbol exporting part is gone from `RcppExports.cpp`.

3.) Create `my_RcppExports.R` in /R, and paste the content from `RcppExports.R`, but adjust the symbol names to what you set in `my_RcppExports.cpp`. This will simply overwrite `RcppExports.R` every time you load the package. Another options is to do // [[Rcpp::export(.mycppfun)]], so these functions will be hidden (if you are not already adjusting the NAMESPACE file). I see no option to get rid of `RcppExports.R` alltogether.

I am happy to still get feedback on this solution. Is there a way to get rid of `RcppExports.R`?